# encrypt ajax service post request data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf, encryption

I have a .net web application that post data to server from javascript via jquery in association with wcf ui services. This enables a non post back modal.

Is it possible to encrypt the data being sent to the server so that using sniffing applications such as fiddler and firebug, the POST of the data cannot be viewed. I want to achieve this for security. The data will need to be read on the server side.

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the request to an ssl endpoint.  The action would be https://something/action.

Setup IIS 7
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis-7/

Setup IIS 6
http://www.petri.co.il/configure_ssl_on_your_website_with_iis.htm

Comment: I am already doing this. But I would like to secure it further if possible

Comment: As long as you have your ssl setup correctly, that should be more than enough.  The only other thing you could do would be to encrypt your form data before it is sent using javascript.  Once it is received on the server, it could be decrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Any encryption performed by javascript on the client side will be reversible on the client as well. At best you could achieve some obfuscation for non-technical users.

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTTPs. Whether its a "traditional" form or XHR SSL\HTTPS is possible.

Note that, with something like firebug (or Chromes debuger's network tab), you'll still be able to see the data... but that's because its part of the browser. An "external" sniffer, like Wireshark or a potential bad guy doing a man-in-the-middle attack, will not see the plain-text data on the wire (but will see encrypted data instead).